# Recovering one specific future in a future composition

Tags: java, vert.x

I am currently developing a feature using vertx and Futures to allow a highly asynchronous processing.

For that, I am making use of future sequentially future composition, consisting of futures for validation, object building, request sending, etc.

I got to a point, where I want to validate a certain object, and if the validation(-future) fails, I want to "recover" it with getting a newly created object.
However, I only want to recover it if exactly the future before failed, and none before that one.

abstracted eg.:

```java
public final Handler<Message<String>> getRequestHandler() {
    return message -> Future.succededFuture(message)
            .compose(Validator.validateMessage()) // returns the messages string/body
            .compose(Validator.validateString()) // returns the functions input string
            .compose(JsonMapper.mapJsonToClass(ObjectDTO.class)) // returns the mapped ObjectDTO
            .compose(LogicFunctions.doOperation()) // returns the same ObjectDTO after applying changes

            // If it fails here, I want to instead return a different ObjectDTO (inside a future)
            .compose(Validator.validateChangedObjectDTO()) // returns the same validated ObjectDTO

            // This Function shall recover the failed Future and return the different ObjectDTO
            .recover(LogicFunctions.getNewObjectDTO()) // returns the new ObjectDTO

            //...
            .onComplete(
                //...
            );
}
```

The compose/recover javadoc says `When this future fails, the failure will be propagated to the returned future and the mapper will not be called.`. This in my understand means, the CompositeFuture won't fail instantly, instead the failure will be passed on until it reaches the end of the composition and all futures "failed".
This means, if one of the early validation Futures fails (eg. `Validator.validateMessage()`), they will pass their failure through until the `recover(LogicFunctions.getNewObjectDTO())` gets called with the passed on `Throwable`.

My `LogicFunctions.getNewObjectDTO()` however expect a programm-state (in my case: an expired token and the need to refresh it) and certain `Throwable` to operate correctly and refresh correctly. If it gets called in a different programm-state, it might have negative sideeffects.

I probably could validate the Throwable inside LogicFunctions.getNewObjectDTO(), however I don't want to jump in and out of futures based on input parameters, or have futures which just pass on errors if its not a certain error they listen for.

Is there a way to ONLY recover if the one prior future failed? If not, am I using a wrong aproach?

Still new to Vertx and honestly also to asynchronous event handling, so please bare with me.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to catch all (other) failures before you `recover` with `LogicFunctions`. That way, only failures from `Validator` will get propagated downstream. You can explicitly configure `Future` to do that:

```
.compose(LogicFunctions.doOperation())
.otherwiseEmpty()
.compose(Validator.validateChangedObjectDTO())
.recover(LogicFunctions.getNewObjectDTO())
```

In that example, I simply map all failures to `null`, using `otherwiseEmpty`. That way, `Validator` will get `null` if anything goes wrong in the prior computations. You can also use `recover` or `otherwise` to map to something else.

If you’re looking for some more fine-grained control of what should happen when, you could checkout SmallRye Mutiny, which is also supported by Vert.x. `Uni` is roughly equal to `Future` but has an `onFailure` method which you can [call with the expected exception](https://javadoc.io/static/io.smallrye.reactive/mutiny/2.3.1/io.smallrye.mutiny/io/smallrye/mutiny/Uni.html#onFailure(java.lang.Class)).